# How to create new row instead of using the same one?

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
$original_array = [
            [
                "group" => "g1",
                "department" => "d1",
                "team" => null,
                "data_col1" => "some_data1",
                "data_col2" => "some_data2"
            ],
            [
                "group" => "g1",
                "department" => "d1",
                "team" => null,
                "data_col1" => "some_data3",
                "data_col2" => "some_data4"
            ],
            [
                "group" => "g1",
                "department" => "d1",
                "team" => "t3",
                "data_col1" => "some_data5",
                "data_col2" => "some_data6"
            ],
            [
                "group" => "g4",
                "department" => "d6",
                "team" => "t11",
                "data_col1" => "some_data7",
                "data_col2" => "some_data8"
            ]
        ];
```

I want to "group" the array into common group/department/team.

I tried the following - I created a new array, then I assign the relevant keys (group/department/team) and otherwise I assign the value:

```
    $new_array = [];

    foreach ($original_array as $row) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            if ($key === "group" || $key === "department" || $key === "team") {
                $new_array[$key] = $value;
            } else {
                $new_array[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
```

The expected result is:

```
[
    0 => [
        group => "g1",
        department => "d1",
        team => null,
        data => [
            0 => [data_col1 => "some_data1", data_col2 => "some_data2"],     
            1 => [data_col1 => "some_data3", data_col2 => "some_data4"]
    ],
    1 => [
        group => "g1",
        department => "d1",
        team => "t3",
        data => [
            0 => [data_col1 => "some_data5", data_col2 => "some_data6"]                   
    ],  
    2 => [
        group => "g4",
        department => "d6",
        team => "t11",
        data => [
            0 => [data_col1 => "some_data7", data_col2 => "some_data8"]
    ]
]
```

But the result is:

```
[
  "group" => "g4"
  "department" => "d6"
  "team" => "t11"
  0 => "some_data1"
  1 => "some_data2"
  2 => "some_data3"
  3 => "some_data4"
  4 => "some_data5"
  5 => "some_data6"
  6 => "some_data7"
  7 => "some_data8"
]
```

why? Looks like it only assigns values to the last row in the original array

Answer (score 0):

This code should give the good result :

```
 foreach ($original_array as $row) {
        $key = md5($row['group'] . $row['department'] . $row['team']);
        if(!isset($new_array[$key])){
            $new_array[$key] = [
                'group' => $row['group'],
                'department' => $row['department'],
                'team' => $row['team'],
                'data' => [],
            ];
        }
        $data = [];
        foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
            if ($k !== "group" AND $k !== "department" AND $k !== "team") {
                $data[$k] = $v;
            }
        }
        $new_array[$key]['data'][] = $data;
    }
```

This give me that :

```
Array
(
    [336a26e12ea082ff360f8482891e137c] => Array
        (
            [group] => g1
            [department] => d1
            [team] => 
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [data_col1] => some_data1
                            [data_col2] => some_data2
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [data_col1] => some_data3
                            [data_col2] => some_data4
                        )

                )

        )

    [f06623fdd946c84a0c0c30378ba3f6f5] => Array
        (
            [group] => g1
            [department] => d1
            [team] => t3
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [data_col1] => some_data5
                            [data_col2] => some_data6
                        )

                )

        )

    [0b284dc4a7dac108ec2b1205a6484056] => Array
        (
            [group] => g4
            [department] => d6
            [team] => t11
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [data_col1] => some_data7
                            [data_col2] => some_data8
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try it asap. Btw is the md5 necessary or I can modify it to be normal array with no keys like the original?

Comment: You have to identify if the array already exists with group, department and team. This a solution, but you  can change if you want. If in the result you don't want a key of the array, you can do a sort($new_array) at the end.

Comment: Thanks. Why `sort` and not something like `array_values` at the end?